# How to ignore nulls in aggregate functions (AVG) when using multiple case statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, average

I am using SQL server to find the average of some columns, but I want to ignore any column that has a value of 0 or null

Table I am reading from:

[image: Table]

My query:

```
SELECT AVG(CASE WHEN [January-Margin] > 0 THEN [January-Margin] ELSE NULL END + CASE WHEN [February-Margin] > 0 THEN [February-Margin] ELSE NULL END) as [Margin-Average] FROM MyTable
```

When using multiple case expressions inside the AVG() function, the column always returns NULL. What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:
As pointed out by @Gordon Linoff - this is an issue with the addition rather than the aggregate function. Can anyone suggest another way of achieving my desired result?

UPDATE:
My desired result:

```
January-Margin  February-Margin March-Margin    AvgMargin
43.111          0.00            0.00            43.111
57.2897         0.00            0.00            57.2897
55.5352         56.8987         0.00            56.2169
```

Comment: Case _expression_. (Returns a value.)

Comment: instead of using `AVG` function you can `sum` and divide by `count() where values >0` this way you can skip 0 values

Comment: @Mark . . . Your desired result is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm, I think you may need to substitute 0.  The issue with the addition, not the average:

```
AVG(CASE WHEN [January-Margin] > 0 THEN [January-Margin] ELSE 0 END +
    CASE WHEN [February-Margin] > 0 THEN [February-Margin] ELSE 0 END
   ) as [Margin-Average]
```

If everything is `0`, then use `NULLIF()` to ignore those rows:

```
AVG(NULLIF(CASE WHEN [January-Margin] > 0 THEN [January-Margin] ELSE 0 END +
           CASE WHEN [February-Margin] > 0 THEN [February-Margin] ELSE 0 END, 0
          )
   ) as [Margin-Average]
```

However, there are no such examples in your question.

EDIT:

Do you simply want this?

```
(AVG(NULLIF([January-Margin], 0) + AVG(NULLIF([February-Margin], 0))) / 2
```

This is kind of like the average of the values in the two columns where the values are not `0`.

The actual average would be:

```
(SUM(NULLIF([January-Margin], 0) + SUM(NULLIF([February-Margin], 0))) / (COUNT(NULLIF([January-Margin], 0)) + COUNT(NULLIF([February-Margin], 0)))
```

Comment: Thanks but when I input zero instead of null like you suggested, SQL server counts the zero as part of the average, lowering the average - which is what I want to avoid

Comment: @Mark . . . For that, you need `NULLIF()` -- but on the entire expression, not the components.  However,  your example data has no rows where both columns are `0`, so this would not affect that.

Answer (score 2):

You should exclude  the values on the where clause. Any operation with nulls return null.

```
(1 + null) = null;
(1 - null) = null;
(3 + 4 + 5 + null) / 4 = null; // that's AVG function, right there
```

I'm finding your table a little bit odd. But anyway you could make a nested select.

```
    select 
(select avg(january-margin) from table where isnull(january-margin,0) > 0) january-margin,
(select avg(february-margin) from table where isnull(february-margin,0) > 0) february-margin
from table
```

and so on.

Note that you'd probably want some join with the outter query table.

Answer (score 1):

How about with a CROSS APPLY and NullIf()

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([January-Margin] money,[February-Margin] money,[March-Margin] money)  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (43.111,0,0)
,(57.289700,0,0)
,(55.535200,56.898700,0)

Select A.* 
      ,B.*
 From @YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( 
               Select AvgMargin = avg(Value)
                From (  values (NullIf([January-Margin] ,0))
                              ,(NullIf([February-Margin],0))
                              ,(NullIf([March-Margin]   ,0))
                      ) B1(value)
            )B
```

**Returns**

```
January-Margin  February-Margin March-Margin    AvgMargin
43.111          0.00            0.00            43.111
57.2897         0.00            0.00            57.2897
55.5352         56.8987         0.00            56.2169
```